# Java Jax rs inteceptors

Tags: java, jax-rs, interceptor

I'm developing a REST service that intercepts every call. The idea is to validate if something is sent on the header like a userid or a token. If it's not present then send a 403. For that I'm overriding **preProcess**.

This is all done but what I can't figure out is how to send a value from the interceptor to the method.
The idea of implementing an intercetpor was to do this for every method so I didn't need to add @HeaderParam in every method but I still need the header information on the methods.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use
@Context HttpHeaders headers

directly in your class and reuse the information in every method.
You can also derive your resource classes from a superclass where you put that annotation. This way many resource classes can share the same behaviour.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response but, if I use this as a var to the class it is null. If I put it in the method (method(@Context HttpHeaders headers)) it works. But the I don't want it like this...

Comment: Since I have an APP singleton that creates new singletons of my classes in every call, I'm able to pass @Context HttpHeaders to the class constructor. This way I can have the header in the class and not needing to put it as a method parameter. So I can say this is a way and accept the answer :) Thank you